# React - Cannot read property 'secure_url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a place to upload images using cloudinary, all works ok but I'm not sure how to check to see if images are in state because I'm getting:

'Cannot read property 'secure_url' of undefined'

secure_url is a property with an image url on the object returned from cloudinary.

State

```
this.state = {
            toDo: [],
            loggedIn: false,
            images: []
        }

ComponentDidMount (Uploaded image)

    componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
            let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

            let dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`notes`);
            dbRef.on("value", (dataObj) => {
                let toDoArr = [];
                let imagesArr = [];
                let dataObjValue = dataObj.val();
                let displayName = user.displayName;
                for(var prop in dataObjValue) {
                    let uploadedImage = dataObjValue[prop][0];
                    dataObjValue[prop].key = prop;
                    dataObjValue[prop].displayName = user.displayName;
                    toDoArr.push(dataObjValue[prop]);
                    imagesArr.push(uploadedImage);
                }

                this.setState({
                    toDo: toDoArr
                });

                this.setState({
                    loggedIn: true
                })

                this.setState({
                    images: imagesArr
                })
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                loggedIn: false
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Upload image method

```
imageUpload(files) {
        const image = files[0];
        const cloudName = 'xxxx';
        const url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/'+cloudName+'/image/upload';
        const timestamp = Date.now()/1000;
        const uploadPreset = 'xxxx';
        const paramsStr = 'timestamp='+timestamp+'&upload_preset='+uploadPreset+'xxxxx';
        const signature = sha1(paramsStr);
        const params = {
            'api_key': xxxxx,
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'upload_preset': uploadPreset,
            'signature': signature
        }

        let uploadRequest = superagent.post(url);
        uploadRequest.attach('file', image);

        for(let key in params) {
            uploadRequest.field(key, params[key]);
        }

        uploadRequest.end((err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                alert(err);
            }

            const uploaded = res.body;

            let imagesArr = [];

            let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            const dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`notes`);

            if(imagesArr.length === 0) {
                imagesArr.push(uploaded);
                dbRef.push(imagesArr);
            }

            if(imagesArr.length >= 1) {
                imagesArr.splice(0, uploaded);
                dbRef.remove();
                dbRef.push(imagesArr);
            }
        });
    }
```

Map through array

```
    uploadedImage = (
        this.state.images.map((image, i) => {
            return (
                <img className="avatar" key={`image-${i}`} src={image.secure_url} alt={image.orginal_filename}/>
            );
        })
    );
```

Comment: Does console logging `this.state.images` actually show that `secure_url` is set in each image?

Comment: Where in your code did you set `secure_url`?

Comment: @Dekel It's being called in `.map` at `src={image.secure_url}`

Comment: but where did you put values inside? There is where you read the values...

Comment: secure_url is a property on the object you get returned from cloudinary.

Answer (score -1):

Here is The bug

let uploadedImage = dataObjValue[prop][0]

Some or all elements returned by this code are undefined. There is no magic in the react. Try to log all images and check which is undefined

At the end you push undefined to images array

Comment: This isn't an answer and would be better suited as a comment to the question.